# Cleaning up WebServer before Exit

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I am new to ASP.Net. I am running a multi-thread application in Asp.Net/C# using ASP.Net Development Server. When I stop the ASP.NET Development Server ( by clicking on Stop button on Web Development From) not all of the threads are killed, so I have to go to the task manager to kill those threads. I just want to know how I can kill those threads automatically whenever ASP.Net Development Server is stopped.

Thanks

Comment: You have to use signaling, or wait and the pool will kill them after 90 seconds (default time)

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that I want to know what is the event passed to the server when the service is being stopped. If I know the event, then, I can handle that via signaling or any other thing. When we have a windows form, by closing the application an event is passed to the code. I want to know how to do the same thing for web service.